# Clarification about tautologies

Tags: logic

On the philosophy SE site, I read this answer regarding tautologies:

https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/102890/67687

According to the answer, the statement

"Business is business" is not a tautology because of a deeper and hidden underlying meaning:

> "Business is business" means in order for a business to be successful
> it is necessary to do things that may hurt or upset people.
>
> So, while these may seem like tautologies when considering the words
> as written, the deeper meanings behind these sayings are clearly not
> tautological.

I believe this wrong. Tautologies should not be evaluated based on hidden meanings but at "face value". Even in philosophy. Am I wrong?

Thanks

Edit: I wanted to clarify.

The question asked on the Philosophy SE site was simply:

Is "Business is business" a tautology

There was no additional information regarding context or the definition of the word business. No apriori information.

All answers were prejudiced (in my opinion) by providing context when it wasn't asked for.

Food is food is a tautology but business is business is not.

Comment: Not sure what you are after here.  In casual speech, people do not speak with mathematical precision...it doesn't make sense to pretend that they do.  And, as to how philosophers use langauge...well, I suggest asking them.

Comment: I think there is a usefull distinction here. The syntax forms a tautology, but the semantics do not. business = business is a tautology, "business is business" = x, where x is as you described is not a tautology

Comment: @MichaelCarey Thanks that's the distinction I was looking for. Which answers my question. How do I mark my question as answered?

Comment: @lulu Thanks, I think Michael's comment set me straight.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban It seems like you got an answer, but I'd like to add that you may like to read about the concepts "sense" and "reference" by Frege. Also you may give yourself an answer to mark as the correct answer.

Comment: "Tautologies should not be evaluated based on hidden meanings,but at "face value"": how can you tell a hidden meaning from a face value? If the hidden meaning is the standard meaning this would mean that the "face value" would be the hidden meaning. Even in logic, if you accept that there are multiples kinds of logic, then you have to accept that the meaning of propositions like $p \lor \neg p$ could be a tautology or not, depending on what logic you are interpreting it. From that, you could argue that your are introducing multiple meanings of the connectives and propositions.

Comment: @StevanV.Saban, because this seems to have been resolved in the comments- there isn't an official "answer" to select in order to mark your question as answered. It is fine to leave it as is, or you can fill in an answer if you want and select it as the official answer.

Comment: @Lostdefinition Thanks. When I read Business is business, I evaluated it as a tautology by syntax only because I was unaware that the statement had another meaning. It confused me when I was informed it wasn't a tautology.

Comment: @MichaelCarey, I think the term syntax is not being well employed here. The syntax can't form a tautology. Syntax is by definition a set of rules of formation that determines a language. The discussed sentence is well constructed in the English syntax. But the question is how to translate this to some more precise language as to preserve the intended meaning to further semantic analysis.

Comment: @Lostdefinition you are right, my usage isn't formal- and I hope it wasn't misleading. I was trying to highlight how with English we can ascertain meaning by looking at the sentence structure and definitions of words ( what I refered to as "syntax") OR we  can consider meaning from a cultural reference and common use perspective, what I refered to as "semantic" perspective. A better description might be: We have a literal perspective, and a symbolic/metaphorical perspective when assessing language

Comment: @MichaelCarey Wording aside, you  pointed out that there is a distinction or more than one possible way to approach a given natural language statement regarding tautologies. And it has to with context and how much information is provided apriori.

Comment: @MichaelCarey How about literal and figurative tautogies for natural language.

Comment: perfect. I think that fits well

Comment: Not sure if you got downvotes because of me. Sorry, I upvoted yours. I posted the question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4767665/are-these-statements-all-tautologies. After it was closed, I posted it at Philosophy. Isn't it ironic? I am a long term target of some highly reputed users on this website, because one of them discriminated against my questions about logic in the logic chatroom and on this website, and some followed his/her/their footsteps when I raised the issues on meta. Then I got banned for years for several times for arguing with them.

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that the statement is NOT a taut in the original sense of propositional logic.  If we move to predicate logic with identity, we can formalize it as B=B, which is an instance of the valid formula x=x.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA "Water is wet" is another example: A figurative tautology but not a literal tautology.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The analogy that comes to mind is a complex number which has a real and imaginary part. Tautologies for natural languages have a literal and a figurative part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, whenever you translate a statement into a formal language and/or evaluate the truth value of a statement, you must determine the *intended* meaning of the statement or formula. For this reason, some texts actually distinguish between a *statement* and a *proposition*, the latter referring to the exact meaning or information content of a statement. For instance, the statements "Florida is south of Georgia" and "Georgia is north of Florida" are actually the same proposition with identical truth values even though they are two distinct statements. Conversely, the statement "Jack was just let go" refers to two distinct propositions, depending on the context. Perhaps someone was holding Jack and released him, or perhaps Jack was fired from his job. Similarly, the truth value of the statement "Jane put down her dog" may be quite different if $(1)$ Jane was holding her dog and placed him on the ground, or $(2)$ Jane had her dog euthanized. Determining the intended meaning of a statement is often an exercise in examining the context in which it appears, and ignoring the intended meaning can easily lead to erroneous conclusions when analyzing the arguments in which they appear.

Comment: I think Michael Carey clarified it. There is not one answer to to a question about tautologies for colloquial statements. There are both syntax and semantics that can be evaluated independently.

Comment: I think @Lost definition makes an astute point about Michael Carey's use of the term "syntax." Reading the statement "Business is business" in natural language and then translating that as a statement about identity, that is, "business = business," necessarily involves interpretation, which must involve determining the intended meaning of the statement if it is to be done properly.

Comment: I understand that Michael's choice of words is in question. I edited my question to clarify further. Part of this is about apriori information.

Comment: How about literal and figurative tautologies for Natural Language?